# Search bar on main layout for all pages laravel 5

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, view, controller

I want to implement search bar function on all pages, like stackoverflow search bar at header.
Currently all my pages `@extends('layouts.app')` for **header** and **footer**.
Where do I place the **html** code? Is it on master layout laravel at `layouts/app.blade.php`?
If so, how do I create the controller for the layout page ?
or Is there a better approach ?

Comment: Create a separate partial view for search and include it in a header. As your header is common to all pages hence ultimately your search will also be common for all pages.

Comment: Can you please share 'layout.app'

Comment: You can create Widget for this (i.e https://github.com/arrilot/laravel-widgets) and call that widget where you require

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your controller code using view composer, to layouts/app as whenever the layout/app object is created it would execute the code which bind to it. You can write this code in App\AppServiceProvider.php boot function() ie-:

```
public function boot()
{
   view()->composer('layouts.app',function($view){

            // Your Controller Logic Goes here

    });
}
```